# Golang, calling parents' method

Tags: oop, object, methods, go

From the example below, is there anyway that Child object can call Parent's method? For instance, I want Child (boy1 and girl1) to call parent's "Remember" method; so parents can remember what Child want them to remember.

Thank you so much

```
package main

import "fmt"

type child struct {
    Name string 
}

func (p *child) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("Child's yelling")
}

type parent struct {
    Name string 
    Children []child
    Memory []string
}

func (p *parent) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("Parent's yelling")
}

func (p *parent) Remember(line string) {
    p.Memory = append(p.Memory, line)
}

func main() {
    p := parent{}
    p.Name = "Jon"
    boy1 := child{}
    boy1.Name = "Jon's boy"
    girl1 := child{}
    girl1.Name = "Jon's girl"
    p.Children = append(p.Children, boy1)
    p.Children = append(p.Children, girl1)
    fmt.Println(p)

    p.Yell()
    for i:=0;i<len(p.Children);i++ {
        p.Children[i].Yell()
    }
}
```

Thanks to @Jim, here's the solution. The pointer is always confusing.

package main

```
import "fmt"

type child struct {
    Name string
    prnt *parent
}

func (p *child) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("Child's yelling")
}

type parent struct {
    Name     string
    Children []child
    Memory   []string
}

func (p *parent) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("Parent's yelling")
}

func (p *parent) Remember(line string) {
    p.Memory = append(p.Memory, line)
}

func main() {
    p := parent{}
    p.Name = "Jon"
    boy1 := child{}
    boy1.Name = "Jon's boy"
    boy1.prnt = &p
    girl1 := child{}
    girl1.Name = "Jon's girl"
    girl1.prnt = &p

    p.Children = append(p.Children, boy1)
    p.Children = append(p.Children, girl1)
    fmt.Println(p)

    p.Yell()
    for i := 0; i < len(p.Children); i++ {
        p.Children[i].Yell()
        p.Children[i].prnt.Remember("test:" + p.Children[i].Name)
    }

    fmt.Println(p.Memory)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a pointer to the parent in the child struct

```
type child struct {
    Name string
    parent *parent
}

func (p *child) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("Child's yelling")
    p.parent.Remember(p.Name + " called")
    p.parent.Yell()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, how to do that with Remember() method? I am getting a nil pointer error.

Comment: @Gon: You can call `Remember` exactly the same way as I call `Yell` here. If the pointer is nil, you haven't assigned a pointer to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I am just a starter of Golang.

Seems Golang convention is CamelCase for class name, and when inherit a base class ("Parent") shouldn't assign a variable name.  `p.Parent` will automatically work, i.e. as follows:

```
type Child struct {
    *Parent   // put at top
    Name string
}

func (p *Child) Yell() {
    fmt.Println("Child's yelling")
    p.Parent.Remember(p.Name + " called")
    p.Parent.Yell()
}
```

Reference:

1. http://arch-stable.blogspot.hk/2012/05/golang-call-inherited-constructor.html
2. https://medium.com/@simplyianm/why-gos-structs-are-superior-to-class-based-inheritance-b661ba897c67

Some other example inherit with non-pointer Parent like:

```
type Child struct {
    Parent   // put at top
    Name string
}
```

Not sure which one is more official and handy yet